# Animating stacked elements on the Z-axis

Tags: css

I have 2 images, one behind the other.
I want to add some 3d effect: increasing the distance between them on the Z axis.
I tried using translateZ property but it doesn't work as I expected, and I'm stuck.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;

}

.scene2 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;

  perspective: 1200px;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
}

.img.a {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  transform:
    translateZ(100px) rotateY(0deg);
    
    animation: 5s infinite  rotate_a;
}



.img.b {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform:
    translateZ(200px) rotateY(0deg);
    animation: 5s infinite  rotate_b;
    
}



@keyframes rotate_a {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate_b {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(400px) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateZ(400px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="scene2">
  <div class="wrap"> 
   <img class="img a" src="https://i.imgur.com/tXtwrPd.jpeg" alt="">
   <img class="img b" src="https://i.imgur.com/IVyU5Im.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</main>
```

I want the first image (.image.b) to come forward, closer to the screen, to have some empty space between the images on the z axis.

Would appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rotating each image, you can try to rotate the `wrap` class and change the distance of each image to the initial `wrap` position.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;

}

.scene2 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;

  perspective: 1200px;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: 5s infinite rotate;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
}

.img.a {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(0deg); /* change this */
  /* animation: 5s infinite  rotate_a; */
}



.img.b {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(0deg); /* change this */
  /*animation: 5s infinite rotate_b;*/
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
/*
@keyframes rotate_a {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate_b {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(400px) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateZ(400px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="scene2">
  <div class="wrap"> 
   <img class="img a" src="https://i.imgur.com/tXtwrPd.jpeg" alt="">
   <img class="img b" src="https://i.imgur.com/IVyU5Im.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</main>
```